# Function to get a string and return same after processing in C

Tags: c, string

I am working on a code which requires a function. This function gets a string as input and returns a string.

What I have planned so far is to get a `str[]`, remove all `$`'s and spaces, and store this in another string which is returned later:

```
char *getstring(char str[])
{
    int i=0;
    char rtn[255];
    while (i<strlen(str))
    {
       if (str[i] != " " || str[i] != "$" )
             rtn[i] = str[i];
       else
             rtn[i] = '';
    } 
    return str;
}
```

I dont feel like this will work. Any ideas?? :-S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem #1:**
Your function returns a pointer to a (temporary) string which is allocated on the stack. This means that once your function ends, the memory for `rtn` is released, and **this invalidates the `char *` pointer that the function returns**.

What you would rather do is:

```
void getstring(char str[], char rtn[])
{
    /* Some processing on rtn... */
}
```

The caller to `getstring` should handle the allocation and deallocation of the string passed as `rtn`.

**Problem #2**:
Your while loop will run indefinitely, because `i` never increases. Put `i++` somewhere inside the loop.

**Problem #3**:
The condition in your `if`-statement is faulty. You compare `str[i]`, which is a `char`, to `" "` or `"$"`, which are string literals (having `'\0'` in the end). This is wrong.
You need to compare them to chars, which are indicated by apostrophes (not quotation marks).
Also, note that the test condition is wrong as well. You need a logical AND operator instead of OR.
 Change the `if`-statement to:

```
if (str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '$')
```

**Problem #4**:
What does `rtn[i] = '';` mean? `''` is an *empty character constant*, which is illegal in C.
Did you want to just skip a character in `str`?

**Problem #5**:
You have indexation problems. Because `str` and `rtn` may obviously be of different length, you need to manage two running indices, one for each string.

**Problem #6**:
`rtn` is not necessarily null-terminated when the function returns. Assign `'\0'` to the end of `rtn` before the function returns (i.e. `rtn[i] = '\0';` after the `while`-loop ends).

---

Here's your code with all the problems mentioned above fixed:

```
void getstring(char str[], char rtn[])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while (i < strlen(str))
    {
       if (str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '$')
             rtn[j++] = str[i];
       i++;
    }
    rtn[j] = '\0';
}
```

And here's a more efficient version that uses pointers instead of indices, and doesn't use `strlen`:

```
void getstring(char *str, char *rtn)
{
    while (*str)
    {
       if (*str != ' ' && *str != '$')
             *rtn++ = *str;
       *str++;
    }
    *rtn = '\0';
}
```

Comment: @C0de_Hard I've added some more problems that I've found :) Regarding the `malloc`, I'd rather not do it. It is recommended that a caller should manage the memory-resources, otherwise you might get spaghetti code and many bugs to follow.

Comment: "What does rtn[i] = ''; mean? '' is an empty character constant, which is illegal in C.
Did you want to just skip a character in str?" Yes you were right!! I just want to skip that character!

Comment: So here is my question.. when i try to just skip $ and spaces this logic works very fine :)
But the below fails... 
I work in UNIX platform. I want to remove those ^M characters using this. When this goes from ^A - ^Z this doesn't seem to work the same. Any idea?

any sort of help is appreciated! :)

Comment: @Code_Hard I believe that `^M` in Unix is the [_carridge return_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return), and you can test it with `if str[i] == '\r'` in C. Also, I suggest you look into the [`dos2unix` command](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html).

Answer (score 1):

It definitely cannot work. You're not incrementing the 'i' counter and the assignment of '' does not skip symbols.

The in-place variant (not an optimal in speed terms)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void getstring(char* str)
{
    int j, i = 0, len = strlen(str);

    while(i < len)
    {
        char ch = str[i];

        if(ch == ' ' || ch == '$')
        {
            /// shift by one
            for(j = i ; j < len + 1; j++) { str[j] = str[j + 1]; }

            len--;
            i--;
        }

        i++;
    } 

    str[len] = 0;
 }

 int main()
 {
      char test_string[] = "Some string $with$ spaces";

      printf("Src = %s\n", test_string);
      getstring(test_string);
      printf("Res = %s\n", test_string);
      return 0;
 }
```

And the variant with reallocation

```
char *getstring(const char* str)
{
    int i_src = 0;
    int i_dest = 0;
    int len = strlen(str);

    char* rtn = (char*)malloc(len + 1);

    while (i_src < len)
    {
       char ch = str[i_src];
       if ( (ch != ' ') && (ch != '$') )
       {
            rtn[i_dest] = ch;
            /// increment destination index here
            i_dest++;
       }
       /// increment the source index always
       i_src++;
    } 

    rtn[i_dest] = 0;

    return rtn;
}
```

Don't forget to free() the result later.

Comment: Viktor, Yes this is helping me indeed to raise a lot of questions!  :) Let me complete and get back to you!

Comment: why didn't you return the str in the first type? I don't see this test_string being declared a global!! :(

Comment: It's on the stack. And it is faster with alloca. I don't see the problems here unless the string is reeeeally long. It's just a unit-test I've made (in the main function) to check that it works. You ask about a function, not the whole task.

Comment: See, I modify the str[] itself. You've asked for in-place version, I did it (my first variant was with the malloc() call, then I added the in-place)

Answer (score 0):

1. If you want to return new string from a function, you should dynamically allocate memory for the string. In your code`char rtn[255];` you allocate memory for `rtn` on the stack, it will be wiped out after exiting from a function. You should write:

   char *rtn = (char *) malloc(strlen(str));

   Of course you should keep tracking on memory to prevent memory leaks and call `free()` to release memory.
2. Assignment of '' does not skip symbol, you should not increment `i` when you see undesirable symbol (and you have missed the increment in your code).
3. You are returning the wrong value, you should return `rtn` instead of `str`.

The correct code will be like:

```
char *getstring(char str[])
{
    int i=0, rtn_pos = 0;
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    char *rtn = (char*) malloc(len + 1);
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i)
       if (str[i] != ' ' && str[i] != '$' )
             rtn[rtn_pos++] = str[i];
    rtn[rtn_pos] = '\0';
    return rtn;
}
```

Comment: Use single quotes when comparing a character literal.

Comment: and use `malloc(strlen(str) + 1)` not only `strlen(str)`

Comment: ouah, thanks for pointing to missing memory byte for '\0'! But it is better to leave malloc casting. Yes, there is no need to cast from malloc in std C, but if code will be compiled as C++ it will be an error.

Comment: The strlen() in the loop is still ugly: the length of the string only needs to be taken once. Also: a for() loop is less accident-prone than the loose `++i;` at the end of the while loop body.

Comment: wildplasser, you are completely right. I'll take your notes into account.

Comment: Guys, you are really great!! It'll be nice if you are my neighbours ;)

Comment: @vkorchagin the test condition in the `if`-statment is wrong, it should be with `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

Better let the caller supply the destination string (the caller probably knows how large it should be), and return somehing it does *not* know: the number of bytes written to the rtn[] array.

```
size_t mygetstring(char *rtn, char *str)
{
    size_t pos, done;

    for (pos=done=0; rtn[done] = str[pos]; pos++)
    {
       if (rtn[done] == ' ' || rtn[done] == '$' ) continue;
       done++;
    } 
    return done; /* number of characters written to rtn[], excluding the NUL byte */
}
```

Comment: whats size_t?? God!! are you talking in C :O ?

Comment: size_t is an unsigned type large enough to contain the size of *any* object. It is for instance  the type of strlen()s return value, or for malloc()s argument. And the type yielded by the sizeof operator.